# Keyboard module to return true or false statements

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard-events

I am currently utilizing the pypi keyboard module and trying to return a statement of true when pressing a key while the key is pressed (e.g. "up" key), and then return false while the key is not pressed. I can initially get the program to print true or false with loops, only problem is I have to break after true or suffer infinite loop prints of true. 
I would like for the program not break unless I hit the esc key.

```
import keyboard
x = keyboard.read_key()
while True:
    try:
        if x == "up":
            print("True")
        elif x != "up":
            print("False")
    except:
        keyboard.wait("esc")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out and I feel silly, I just wanted to ask the question to get the thought process going.
I ended up with:

```
import keyboard
import time
bulb = False
def LightSwitch():
    global bulb
    if bulb == False:
        print("The light is off")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        bulb = True
    else:
        print("The light is on")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        bulb = False
while True:
    keyboard.add_hotkey("up", LightSwitch)
    keyboard.wait()
```